# Ratio question on parallel sides

Tags: ratio

Besides of knowing the ratio of two sides is in proportion, I don't know how to go further.

[image]

Comment: Use $6a:b::8b:3a $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the sides with arrows are pairwise parallel, we know $\frac{6a}{b}=\frac{8b}{3a}$.

Then cross multiply, we get $18a^2=8b^2$.

$\Rightarrow \frac{a^2}{b^2}=\frac{8}{18}=\frac{4}{9}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}=\frac{2}{3}$ (since $a>0$ and $b>0$)

So, $a:b=2:3$